# Populating Selectize.js Dropdown with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, html-select, selectize.js

I'm building a webapp using `flask`, and am trying to populate a [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) single item select box with a list of countries defined as a Python variable in the `flask` app.

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52435224/json-dump-not-converting-python-list-to-js-array/52435603#52435603), I managed to load a Python list to JavaScript in `<script>` tags by using the following code in `flask`:

```
def select():
    countries = ["UK", "US", "GER"]
    return render_template("select_menu.html", countries = json.dumps(countries))
```

I am then able to load `countries` to be displayed in `select_menu.html` using following the JavaScript statement:

```
var countries = {{countries | safe}}
```

However, when I try to use this method in combination with Selectize.js, like so:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    var countries = {{countries | safe}};

    $("#search").selectize({
      valueField: 'val',
      labelField: 'val',
      searchField: ['val'],
      options: countries,
    });
  });
</script>
```

No options are loaded.
The html part looks like this:

```
<div class='exampleSearch'>
  <select id="search">
<option value="">select</option>
  </select>
```

Additionally, the above Selectize.js codesnippet works just fine when I define `countries` in the JS as:

```
var countries = [{val:"UK"},
                {val:"US"},
                {val:"GER"}]
```

Note: defining the Python list in `flask` this way did not help.

Can anyone tell me how I should define my Python `countries` variable so I could load it into the JS and use it to populate the Selectize dropdown.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python code is equivalent to the following:

```
json.dumps(["UK", "US", "GER"])
```

which will render in JS as a list of strings:

```
["UK", "US", "GER"]
```

But the library you are using expects a list of objects:

```
[{val:"AppleScript"},
 {val:"Asp"},
 {val:"BASIC"}]
```

Try replacing your Python `select` function with:

```
def select():
    countries = [
        {"val": "UK"},
        {"val": "US"},
        {"val": "GER"}
    ]
    return render_template("select_menu.html", countries = json.dumps(countries))
```

Comment: I'll try this out and get back to you today! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick! I was afraid It would be a problem if the first half of the obj would be a string

Comment: In JavaScript the two objects `{foo: 10}` and `{"foo": 10}` are identical. In Python only the latter syntax is correct (and would also represent the same object).

Comment: That's good to know! I've been using Python for over a year now, but have only just started looking at JavaScript the past 72 hours!

Comment: Okay. Be careful about type coercion. In JS `22 + "22"` is valid and will not give the same result as in Python (which would raise an exception). If you forget converting user-input from text to the proper types you might end up with a valid syntax but will leave you with incorrect data.